Is there a way to decode a JSON key to a differently named codable property in struct in swift
I have and API that I am making a network request to and the API returns some JSON data.
From what I've seen, the most common and generally accepted way to handle that JSON data and work with it, is to make a Codable struct and then decode the JSON data to the struct Like this Hacking with Swift example.
I'm running into an issue though and need some help. There is some persistence code that is included in the Xcode project (that Xcode is not letting me alter) that utilizes a struct named "Item". The API I'm using has a key in the JSON also named "Item". When I make my Codable struct I (predictably) get an error saying that there is an "Invalid redeclaration of 'Item'" since its declared in persistence code.
My question: Is there a way to make a Codable struct and still be able to use the JSON decoding to map the "Item" field from the JSON data to a differently named field in the Codable struct (i.e. something like Items, or Products).
So lets say this is the JSON Data:
{
    "items": [
                 { "id": 12345 },
                 { "id": 67890 },
                 { "id": 10111 },
                 { "id": 21314 }
    ]
}

And this is the struct:
struct Order: Codable {
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let id: Int
}

is there a way to rename Item (in my struct) to something else and still have the item from the JSON decoded to the struct?

What is wrong with the code above? I am pretty sure it will work with this JSON.

yes you can "...map the "Item" field from the JSON data to a differently named field in the Codable struct (i.e. something like Items, or Products)",
using enum CodingKeys:... for example:
struct Order: Codable {
    let products: [Product]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case products = "items"
    }
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let product: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case product = "id"
    }
}

// alternatively keeping the id
struct Product: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
}


I just want to make sure I'm understanding correctly.
the Coding keys enum in the order struct is saying that an alternative name for Products is items (as seen in the JSON). In the Product struct an alternative name for the product property is id?

You can give your Swift models struct (Order, Product) any name you want, and using enum CodingKeys
you can give any name for their properties (eg: let products) to map to the corresponding JSON data objects keys (eg: items).
The enum CodingKeys in struct Order will tell the JSONDecoder() to decode the JSON objects with key items of the data, into the stored property products in struct Order.
See the docs at CodingKeys for more info.

Note, using enum CodingKeys will not change the JSON data. It is just  saying map the JSON object key items of the data to the struct Order property products.  So it is saying, the JSON data objects key items becomes products property in the struct Order.
Each of those is decoded as type struct Product, that maps the JSON data object with key id. And this id key can be renamed to product if you want it to be call that in the struct Product.

So, if I understood correctly, you have already a struct/class named Item, so here are a few alternatives from your initial code:
struct Order: Codable {
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let id: Int
}

The struct name doesn't have to be Item, you can just rename it:
struct Order: Codable {
    let items: [Product]
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let id: Int
}

You can nest the Item:
struct Order: Codable {
    let items: [Order.Item] //or [Item]

    struct Item: Codable {
        let id: Int
    }
}

So it's still "Item", but it's Order.Item. Inside the Order, it should try to use Order.Item by default when writing Item.
If you need to differentiate them later, it's Order.Item and App.Item where App is your AppName, or Framework.Item if Item is inside another framework.

Wouldn't the Item struct defined in Order still cause the same "Invalid redeclaration of 'Item'" error to appear (since there is already an item struct declared in the persistence code).

It shouldn't, because Order.Item isn't a redeclaration of App.Item.
